# Why are my answers showing lower than usual?

Tags: support, answers, sorting

Recently, my answers are showing at the bottom of the page, even though I got good scores on those answers.

- [Android Fragments and animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation/46357316#46357316)
- [ProgressDialog is deprecated.What is the alternate one to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373007/progressdialog-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternate-one-to-use/45613741#45613741)

How do I change this back?

Comment: Your sorting is probably by 'active' or 'oldest' and not by 'votes'.

Comment: @Glorfindel i am daily active as well i will update my answer after some days sir..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you chose to sort them by "oldest" and not "votes", the default:

On the top right of the top answer are the sort buttons. Just click "votes" and it should appear at the top (as they are the highest-voted).

> [image: Answer sorting arrows]

Comment: Recently i updated my answer...still it's showing bottom

Comment: @GowthamanM Did you change the sort order back?

Comment: can you explain little more....i donot understand what you are saying about  **sort order back**...

Comment: @GowthamanM I've edited in a screenshot. Those buttons are the ways to sort the answers. Yours is set to "oldest"; you just need to set it to "votes".

Comment: thank you so much sir...i understand very clearly...thanks once again...